# Seeking population of each Indian village and town?

Tags: data, census, population, india

There are over 600,000 villages in India.
I want to get the population of each of the village according to 2011 census.
I searched the http://censusindia.gov.in website for hours but could not get data for all the villages in a single file (of any format) or a few files.

In the population finder page, I could search for villages one by one, but could not get the data for all the villages in less time.

Can you inform me where to get the data?

Answer (score 3):

You can get population data from [Geonames](http://www.geonames.org).

Not sure about the source of the population data, although it seems that such data coincides with Wikipedia's population data, which is from 2011.

You would also need to validate that there are more than 600.000 Indian villages in Geonames.

Regarding an automated way, you could follow [this tutorial](http://linfiniti.com/2011/03/fun-with-geonames/) by Tim Sutton for extracting, storing and visualizing the data in QGIS.